# correlation matrix test: is this code correct or is it missing a multiple comparisons correction?

Tags: r, correlation, multiple-comparisons, correlation-matrix

I have $m$ variables $x_1,\dots,x_m$, measured in $N$ **independent** tests $\{x_{i1},\dots,x_{im}\}_{i=1}^N$, leading to the design matrix $X$. I noted that the demo function `corrplot_intro.r` from the R package `corrplot` includes a nice function `cor.mtest` (reported below), which computes the pairwise correlations for $x_1,\dots,x_m$ in the sample $X$ and reports the corresponding $p$-values:

```
cor.mtest <- function(mat, conf.level = 0.95){
    mat <- as.matrix(mat)
    n <- ncol(mat)
    p.mat <- lowCI.mat <- uppCI.mat <- matrix(NA, n, n)
    diag(p.mat) <- 0
    diag(lowCI.mat) <- diag(uppCI.mat) <- 1
    for(i in 1:(n-1)){
        for(j in (i+1):n){
            tmp <- cor.test(mat[,i], mat[,j], conf.level = conf.level)
            p.mat[i,j] <- p.mat[j,i] <- tmp$p.value
            lowCI.mat[i,j] <- lowCI.mat[j,i] <- tmp$conf.int[1]
            uppCI.mat[i,j] <- uppCI.mat[j,i] <- tmp$conf.int[2]
        }
    }
    return(list(p.mat, lowCI.mat, uppCI.mat))
}
```

However, it seems to me that no correction for multiple comparisons is performed, while it would be needed because I'm (blindly) testing for all correlations ([see this nice answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/90025/58675)). So, the $p$-values reported are not actually reliable. Am I right? Could you help me correct the code so that the effect of doing $m^2$ comparisons is correctly taken into account?